# protractor testing on token authorization pages

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

How can I test inner app pages with token authorization? It always throw me on login page with test failure. I added in config file 'accessToken' or 'tiken' with token value, but without success.

Comment: You question is not so understandable... But as my understanding I think you should write test scripts to login before performs any test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write script, which will:
1. (optionally) install test user into application
2. login to application

Put it either into protractor-conf.js::onPrepare function (to be executed only once before all tests), or into beforeEach block (to be executed each time before every test)